# Flutter: Firestore: When are snapshot().listener connections severed?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use several firestore listeners through the entire lifecycle of my app. I want to know when these connections are severed so I can instead cancel them myself and re-establish them appropriately. It appears when the app is minimized and maximized, the listeners are occasionally lost and crash the app if used. I can't find documentation on when this connection is terminated, so I'm uncertain of when should handle the procedure myself.

Using the `didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state)` would be the obvious spot. However, this function triggers when a user uses the Camera or Gallery plugin I use and would cause unnecessary halts and starts to the listener. I have tried wrapping the camera and gallery usage in a bool to prevent `didChangeAppLifecycleState` from firing with no success.

Second question. Is pausing and resuming a listener sufficient? or do they need to be cancelled and reestablished?

Comment: There is a mention of [detaching listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) . Its not dart specific though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. What listeners are you referring to? Is your question about running Flutter background processes? using `didChangeAppLifecycleState` can be an option as there are [different states](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) that your application can be in

Comment: I updated the question. I was referring to Firestore snapshot listeners. I figured didChangeAppLifecycleState was the place to do it. However, I face misfiring due to some camera plugins

Comment: Pausing and resuming states sound reasonably good as you won't need to implement them over and over. Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Pausing and resuming worked! :D I've been crash-free for a few days now. It appears that the connections can be lost if the app is in the background. Not an issue with the app in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pause and resume all listeners in: 
didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state).

I have been crash-free for a few days now and everything works fine. There doesn't seem to be a point where listeners can be lost when the app is active in the foreground. I did so by keeping all listener variables in a static class that managed the state of each listener.

Comment: BONUS: when you resume listeners, they get all the document changes made while they were paused! :D